# "In a list" vs. "on a list"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

In the following sentence, should I use *in* or *on*?

> If I ever make a list, not only will you be **in/on** it, you'll top it, too.

Comment: "I" must be capitalized. There must be a space after each comma. "Not only you'll be" should be "not only will you be". And a comma before "too" would be nice. *This stuff matters*, and if you don't pay attention to it, choosing between "in" and "on" will be the least of your worries.

Comment: @RegDwight I have just spent the last 5 minutes trying to find a grammatical or spelling mistake in that comment :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should go with **on**. I would phrase your sentence

> If I ever make a list, not only will you be on it, you'll be on top of it.

On [just-the-word](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=list_N%20pobj_of%20on_PREP) you can take a look at many examples. For instance:

> The first number on the list was a posh-sounding hotel.

Comment: Nice! I've not seen "just-the-word" before.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a list as a container of names/persons then it is valid to say.

> If I ever make a list, not only will you be **in** it, you'll be on top of
>   it.