# Differences between "in a list" and "on a list"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, in-on

Generally speaking, is there any difference between saying *"in a list"* vs. *"on a list"*?

There's already a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65006/in-a-list-vs-on-a-list), but that was about one specific example with a specific answer; if possible, I'd like to know if there's a general rule or if there are situations where one form would be preferred over the other.

Examples:

*"to be in the list"* vs. *"to be on the list"*

*"to save in the list"* vs. *"to save on the list"*

*"to put in the list"* vs. *"to put on the list"*

etc.

Comment: Hello, mguassa. What research have _you yourself_ done? These are all Googlable, and ripe for Google Ngram analyses.

Comment: Although that question was more specific than yours, I think the answers  generalize to yours as well. Why do you think the answers there are only relevant to that use?

Comment: This comes up often here; [this explains the usages](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/74373/15299). Turns out it all depends on how you think of the list -- 3-dimensional information stash or 2-dimensional paper/screen dump.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you, that's the best answer I could read on the topic, I've never thought to see it in that way. Answer and comment upvoted!